# Using Github interface for single commit pull request

Tags: git, github

I have been struggling a lot in creating a pull request for a single commit.  I have followed this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256021/send-a-pull-request-on-github-for-only-latest-commit) (command line), but still after creating the new branch i am seeing 9 unwanted commits in my pull request with the one i want.  I want to create a request for only single commit.

Is this possible **through interface** OR if any other way to **create single commit pull request**

Comment: I think it is because you have different histories and possible a merge from something else. You should branch from the upstream branch to which you are creating the pull request and cherry-pick the commit you want.

Comment: well i am trying to do same, my upstream branch in master and i create a branch.  But when i push that branch and try to do a pull request it is listing other commits too..

Comment: In that case dont do pull request do git fetch and then merge the commit that you want manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your branches have diverged, and it's *impossible* to simply drag the top commit off the other branch with a pull request.  What you need is a cherry pick: Check out the remote branch, create a new branch *from that state*, and then cherry pick your single commit onto the new branch. Then you can issue a pull request for the new branch.

Comment: Master is my current branch, i created a new branch out of master and cherry-picked my commit and pushed my branch to github.com.  It still shows all commits with the one i wanted in pull request :(

Comment: What branch are you trying to merge your changes into?

Comment: The branch where i had my commit was a different branch, i merged it onto my master.  Now i am trying to create pull request from my master

Comment: You can't base your new branch of *your master*. You need to check out the branch you're issuing a pull request into, and cherry pick onto that branch.

Comment: Ok, i did a git checkout origin/mybranch (this is the branch i pushed the commit).  Now i created a new branch out of it and cherry picked the commit.  I pushed it again and it same.. i am sorry for this