# git commit fix to project owner

Tags: git, github, commit

I forked [binux/pyspider](https://github.com/binux/pyspider) and made some change.Today I found a bug and want to commit a fix to the owner.
I have 4 commit for now, the [last commit](https://github.com/binux/pyspider/commit/6b8fc09133b11ff8f243cdcf90fa559ee9cf4f26) contain two files(one file to fix bug, one file my edit). 
And I found the most easy understanding way [by John Naegle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256021/send-a-pull-request-on-github-for-only-latest-commit).
But I got error here:

```
mithril@KASIM /E/Project/pyspider (master)
$ git checkout pullrequest
Switched to branch 'pullrequest'

mithril@KASIM /E/Project/pyspider (pullrequest)
$ git pull https://github.com/binux/pyspider.git
From https://github.com/binux/pyspider
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.

mithril@KASIM /E/Project/pyspider (pullrequest)
$ git branch
  master
* pullrequest
$ git cherry-pick 6b8fc09133b11ff8f243cdcf90fa559ee9cf4f26
error: could not apply 6b8fc09... fix pymongo dump error
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'

mithril@KASIM /E/Project/pyspider (pullrequest|CHERRY-PICKING)
$ git diff
diff --cc pyspider/scheduler/scheduler.py
index 48a7888,a2f5aaf..0000000
--- a/pyspider/scheduler/scheduler.py
+++ b/pyspider/scheduler/scheduler.py
```

I run the command under my pyspider clone folder, is it wrong?
Does that means I have to revert changes of `scheduler.py` and add them back after I switch to master branch?
Could I just add `pyspider/webui/result.py` to the pullrequest branch without influence to mater brach?
Should I go to a new folder to create and get this new branch?
I am not very familiar with git, I fear I would do something wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I know Git is very powerful:
1. create a new branch and make change, would not affect other branches.
2. I can create branch with a `SHA key` (every commit has a unique key)

I have made my first the pullrequest, it's feel good.