# GitHub Website/Windows app - how do you create "pull request" from single commit?

Tags: github, github-for-windows

Currently i'v forked some repo on github.

Changed something for my needs, pushed to my master branch, changed something related to core master branch.

Now i want to "pull request" these **( *last* ) commit only** to core master branch, but when i create pull request it has *2 commits* in it.

I need a solution, wich will allow me to "pull request" **only 1 commit** trought *GitHub Website* or *GitHub for Windows app*.

I'v read about *git cherry pick*, but these solution requires cmd/git atc.
But what i need: **Website** or **Windows app** to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send a pull request on GitHub for only latest commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256021/send-a-pull-request-on-github-for-only-latest-commit)

Comment: as i mentioned i'v found a solution with cmd/git cherry pick. But there's no answer for how to do it not using cmd/git.